# How To Scrape Values in Selenium Using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I'm Trying To Scrape Values in option tag with css selector but i can't:

I Want to scrape values attribute in option tag for example `<option value='i want to scrape this'>text</option>`

Here is another Screenshot so you can understand better:

[image]

in the option tag i want to scrape values not text

You Can See Here is the option values screenshot:

[image]

I Want also to scrape values here:

Here is my code:

```
cur = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#id_currency')
country = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('search-form-place-country')
items = len(cur)

with open('cur.csv','w') as s:
    for i in range(items):
        s.write(cur[i].text + ',' + country[i].text + '\n')
```

Any Help Will Be Appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What values you want to get?

Comment: in the option tag i wan't to scrap values attribute

Comment: You want to fetch Country name?

Comment: Question Updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the *values* with in the `<option>` tag with using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select_places = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.search-form-place.select.form-control"))
for option in select_places.options:
    print(option.get_attribute("value"))
```

Comment: Getting Error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cur.py", line 11, in <module>
    select_places = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select.search-fo
rm-place.select.form-control"))
NameError: name 'Select' is not defined`

Comment: @HamzaMirchi Added the imports, checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select` class, it is specifically for `<select>` dropdowns

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

dropDown = driver.find_element_by_id('search-form-place-country')
select = Select(dropDown)
with open('cur.csv','w') as s:
    for option in select.options:
        s.write(option.get_attribute('value') + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

just select them based on the option tag.

`country= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('option')`

New for loop:

```
    for i in range(items):
        s.write(cur[i].text + ',' + country[i].get_attribute["value"] + '\n')
```

Comment: no i don't want whole option tag i want option tag and inside there i want to scrap values attribute

Comment: I Want to scrap `values` attribute in `option` tag for example `<option value='i want to scrap this'>text</option>`

Comment: then just replace the .text part in your for loop with .getAttribute("value")

Comment: Sorry the syntax is get_attribute() not getAttribute()